# sfdp crashing on large graphs

Tags: bigdata, graphviz

I am trying to draw a graph with about 7 million nodes using sfdp.
The command call, say

```
time sfdp -Tps bg.dot -o bg_sfdp.ps
```

crashes with a segmentation fault in a little less than 3 mins.

As with CoreDumps in general, I have a hard time understanding where the problem is coming from.  The machine I am using has a fair chunk of RAM (48GB).

I have tried other output formats (PNG, SVG) to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a way for me to instruct graphviz (dot,neato, SFDP, twopi, circo) on how much memory it is allowed to use?  The run seems to top out at using 10% of 48GB.

Comment: Here is the last verbose displayed line right before it chokes:
   
    fontname: "Times-Roman" resolved to: (ps:pango  Times Roman)(PangoCairoFcFont) "Nimbus Roman No9 L, Regular" /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n021003l.pfb
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)

    real    2m42.266s
    user    2m23.991s
    sys     0m10.143s